# mysql same records returned even if I give a wrong equality value

Tags: mysql, sql

Query 1

```
SELECT supplier.supplierId, supplierName, supplierTypeId, iconFileName, description, url, defaultLanguageCode
                    FROM supplier, supplier_service_area
                    WHERE supplier.supplierId = supplier_service_area.supplierId
                    AND postalCode = '72631dsdf'
                    ORDER BY supplierTypeId, supplierName, supplier.supplierId, supplierServiceAreaId limit 0,2;
```

Query 2

```
SELECT supplier.supplierId, supplierName, supplierTypeId, iconFileName, description, url, defaultLanguageCode
                    FROM supplier, supplier_service_area
                    WHERE supplier.supplierId = supplier_service_area.supplierId
                    AND postalCode = '72631'
                    ORDER BY supplierTypeId, supplierName, supplier.supplierId, supplierServiceAreaId limit 0, 2;
```

I am giving postalCode = '72631dsdf' in query 1 and postalCode = '72631' in the second query.

But both queries are returning correct results.Why is that so ? The second query is valid.But the first query is also returning same records.Its as if LIKE condition has been applied , but I am using '='

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL usually allows various implicit conversions, which is what is happening here: the "invalid" input is being silently converted to a REAL.

From http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26bacb/11 (see the section below as this shows conversions result but not "why"):

```
SELECT
  ("72631dsd") as a,
  (0.0 + "72631dsd") as b,
  (0.0 + "a72631dsd") as c;
```

The results are:

```
a           |  b      |  c
"72631dsd"  |  72631  |  0
```

---

The rules in MySQL are covered in [12.2. Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html):

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, *MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa* ..
>
> The following rules describe how conversion occurs for comparison operations: ..
>
> - [...]
> - In all other cases, the arguments are [implicitly converted and] compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make mysql throw an exception ? Or should I do client side validation. advice ?

Comment: @TitoCheriachan I do know of a way to disable these implicit conversions. This sort of validation should be done as required; at least to the extent of domain-typed values assigned to variables (e.g. read-convert $_POST["ZIP"] as an integer) and more if useful error messages can be generated or if confusing/incorrect behavior can be avoided. And parameterized queries should still be used: this is validation (along business rules), not sanitization!